# Angular and scroll to top when redirect

Tags: angular

Is there in angular something like scrolling to top of website while url change is detected? If not, how to scroll to the top while there is redirect(or navigate) in typescript and also html files?

Edit:

I saw in one of topics:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
    if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
      return;
    }
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  });
}
```

but in my application it does not working. I think there's problem with line

```
document.body.scrollTop = 0;
```

, cause when I swap it with console.log('tmp') it detects route changing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `router-outlet` has a method `activate`, which is called when a component is loaded. You can utilize that and in your app-component scroll to top. So in your `app-component`:

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
```

TS:

```
onActivate(event: Event) {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Great, glad to hear :)

Answer (score 2):

Now with the latest update you can enable this option in root routing , like below -

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
      RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
         scrollPositionRestoration: 'top'
      })
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

For more in details see here -

- [Deep dive into Angular Routing — Scrolling to top, Debugging and lot more](https://medium.com/@PardeepJain/deep-dive-into-angular-routing-scrolling-to-top-debugging-and-lot-more-a995c08498d3)